# Authenticating Custom made SMTP server

Tags: c#, smtp

I have made my own SMTP server in C# and I want to provide the option to make it require authentication. I can't find anywhere on Google that shows what responses and requests the SMTP should send/receive in order to authenticate with the client.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [RFC 2554 (SMTP Service Extension for Authentication)](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2554.txt).

There is a complete tutorial at

http://www.fehcom.de/qmail/smtpauth.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try with theses lines - SmtpClient.Credentials property

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
NetworkCredential networkCredential = 
    new NetworkCredential("username", "password"); 

client.Credentials = networkCredential ;
```

you have article here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.credentials.aspx

Comment: He's writing his own SMTP server and wants to know how to implement the AUTH protocol.  How does this help?

Comment: SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(param); where param is host of your server
            /

Comment: @Candie - HOW will his custom server understand the credentials you're sending it?!?!

Comment: the credentials are just sample Frank

Comment: @Candie: You are showing client side code that calls a server.  The OP wants to know how to *write* the server.

Comment: As @EricJ.said this code is for sending an email to an already available. I was asking for what SMTP requests and responses I should expect to receive/send so I can enable authentication on my custom made SMTP server